# Pull apk from fire base to my local testing environment

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

My organizations uses Google Firebase to distribute apps to manual testers. For automated testing, we need access to the app apk/ipa directly to pass the local path to appium.

I see under App Distribution / Releases in Firebase Console that there is now a "Download" button which does what I need. However, is there a corresponding Firebase CLI endpoint or a way I could even just use curl to grab the needed build from firebase and download it?